# How to use Delphi created ActiveX DLL in .NET environment like VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, delphi, c#-4.0, activex

I am running 32bit development environment with Win 7 and VS2010.
I was able to register the Delphi created ActiveX in Windows7

```
regsvr32.exe "C:\Program Files\MyApp\Test\DelphiActiveX.dll"
```

Then I added reference in my VS2010 Windows Form project.

I tried the c# 4.0 way of using ActiveX with a dynamic object but it is not working. Nothing happens.

```
// c# 4.0 
dynamic myActiveXLink = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DelphiActiveX.DelphiActiveXLink"));
//dynamic myActiveXLink = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(""));
myActiveXLink.SearchByName("FName1", "LName1");
```

SearchByName method should start a third party application installed on the computer.

EDIT: The CreateInstance() is executed without error.
Now I am getting Exception at the  myActiveXLink.SearchByName() call:

[image]

Exactly the same code works fine under WindowsXP and VS2010, but fails under Windows7 32bit and VS2010.

Comment: Not enough info. Does `CreateInstance()` successfully create the object?  Does the object implement the `IDispatch` interface? Are any errors being reported? Have you tried debugging your DLL to see what `SearchByName()` is actually doing when called?

Comment: I get an exception now, after restarting the machine. See the EDIT above. I don't have access to the DLL code. Thanks.